# Jquery ui tabs are wrapping to another line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery tabs on my website but on smaller screens the tabs wrap to another line is there a way to keep the tabs from doing this?

Comment: Read: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/queryui-tabs-how-to-keep-them-on-a-single-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the link from NAVEED and it was messy. If you can live with only supporting browsers that implement inline-block, try:

```
jQuery('#mytabs')
    .tabs()
    .find('.ui-tabs-nav')
        .css('white-space','nowrap')
        .css('overflow','hidden')
        .find('li')
            .css('display','inline-block')
            .css('float','none')
            .css('vertical-align','bottom');
```

Quick & dirty, not tested.

Fiddle (js): http://jsfiddle.net/yxPa6/4/

Fiddle (css): http://jsfiddle.net/kUuTE/2/

Comment: For anyone else coming to this,  you don't need to do this within jQuery. You can just specify this in your css like #mytabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden
} and #mytabs.ui-tabs-nav li {
    display: inline-block;float:none;vertical-align: bottom;
}

Answer (score 1):

Adding scroll buttons is a nice alternative to hiding the tabs that won't fit on one line. This can be done easily with the [jquery-ui-tabs-paging](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-tabs-paging/) plugin, take a look at the example [page](http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/ui.tabs.paging.html).